# 80s/90s fantasy movie where flattened wizard slides down stairs

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie I think I saw at a very young age.  I recall a boy being with a hopeless wizard/magician and in one scene, the wizard/magician is at the top of the stairs with a much more powerful witch who then makes the wizard flat and he slides down the stairs.

Whilst the wizard is recovering, the witch then walks with the boy, I think trying to dissuade him from keeping company with the wizard.  The wizard/magician was dressed as a magician in a black tuxedo and the witch sort of like Padme in *Star Wars Episode 1 - The Phantom Menace* with the red outfit on.

I think it was from the 1990s, or perhaps 80s from what I remember, but it was definitely in color.

Comment: There's a late 70s movie called Mandrake the Magician. I don't remember that scene, but the wizard does wear a tux and a tall stovepipe formal hat if I remember correctly. I'm putting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't remember that specific scene.

Comment: @FoxMan2099 - I've looked at that and I'm pretty sure that's not it by the looks of it the movie I'm thinking of was made later.  Thanks for the effort though

Comment: no problem, and FWIW, I have no idea why someone downvoted this question. Oh well, who cares? Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*A Simple Wish* (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120133/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_40) starring Martin Short. Most of what you describe matches, though the protagonist is a young girl (Mara Wilson) instead of a boy, and Martin isn't dressed in a tuxedo, but rather an old-fashioned-y suit.

You can even get a glimpse of the "***flat and sliding down the stairs***" scene in the trailer on Youtube.

Comment: This is definitely it - not quite as I remember it, but it was a very long time ago that I saw this.  Great work!